# What causes a sudden consistent HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error in an asp.net core 3.1 mvc app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, iis-express

Yesterday, all was well. Today, all of a sudden, one route in an asp.net core 3.1 MVC app I have has started producing this error:

*"HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server. "*

All other routes work fine.

What is the likely cause of this?

Comment: There is no way to guess. Enable FRT to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: it's interpreting that path/route as one to a directory.  It then tries to find the default page in that directory and doesn't find it (usually "index"?).  It then decides to display the contents of the directory and it can't (and shouldn't for security reasons) because of a configuration.   Maybe include the route (URL) that's not working and one that is... it might give a clue as to what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

1.Open up IIS Manager.

2.Add the website by right clicking on "Default website" and choose "Add application".

3.Enter any name as alias type and the load that website in the physical path and click OK.

4.Then go to the Features View of that Loaded Website and double click on the "Directory Browsing".

5.Click on "Actions" work space and change the "Disable" state to "Enable" state.

6.Then Refresh the Default Website.